# Interface annotation and ProGuard

Tags: java, android, proguard

I'm having an issue with my custom annotation after running ProGuard.

Here is relevant code:

**Annotation**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface MyAnnotation {

}
```

**class A extends B**

```
...
@MyAnnotation
public interface CustomInterface {
}
...
```

**abstract class B**

```
// mClass never found since MyAnnotation seems to be disappeared
// after obfuscation
for (Class<?> c : getClass().getClasses()) {
    for (Annotation annotation : c.getAnnotations()) {
        if (annotation instanceof MyAnnotation) {
            mClass = c;

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried many keep statements found in related posts, but none of them suite this case.

Running code without ProGuard correctly finds the class for mClass member.

ProGuard config has:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

following code always works for me

-keepattributes *Annotation*

Answer (score 0):

Following declaration seems to fix the problem:

```
-keep @com.mycompany.myapp.MyAnnotation interface * {
*;
}
```